# c# await task - local variables being changed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I've just started implementing async programming into some methods that I'm writing.

The business logic is to accept inbound calls, process an item if it's not already in the global cache, or if it is, simply update the entry which will then be processed later in the code.

However I'm seeing some strange behaviour that I can't get my head around.  My unit test submits two requests to my QueueProcessor method (there is a 2 second delay between each call).  For testing I have purposefully used task.delay in another method that the QueueProcessor will call out to when processing a request.  This simulates a real world test case where we hold back additional requests while the first one is processed.

I'm using a local variable in scope of my sub method called ProcessRoutine.  But for some reason when the second call comes in to update the global cache, the local variable that is only in scope in the ProcessRoutine method is also changed.

Furthermore the second request will only action logic that updates the global cache variable and then stop.  So no other code is fired.  I've confirmed this through my logs.  I just can't see why on earth a passed dataset in the ProessRoutine method could be changed in this way.

```
public async Task<bool> QueueProcessor(RtcPluginModel_IncidentModel passInModel)
    {


        //Ensure the processing cache is instantiated
        if (QueueGlobalVariables.processingCache == null)
        {
            QueueGlobalVariables.processingCache = new List<tempTicketData>();
        }

        try
        {



            tempTicketData ticketItem = (tempTicketData)passInModel;

            ticketItem.timeStamp = DateTime.Now;

            var checkItemExistsInProcessingCache =
                QueueGlobalVariables.processingCache.Find(
                    x => x.PAName == passInModel.PAName);


            if (checkItemExistsInProcessingCache != null)
            {

                var result = QueueGlobalVariables.processingCache.Remove( QueueGlobalVariables.processingCache.Find(
                    x => x.PAName == passInModel.PAName && x.recordId == passInModel.recordId));

                QueueGlobalVariables.processingCache.Add(ticketItem);

                logger.Trace("Stopping update branch of code as no further action needed at this point.");
            }
            else
            {

                QueueGlobalVariables.processingCache.Add(ticketItem);

                do
                {

                    var cycleTickets = QueueGlobalVariables.processingCache.Find(
                        x => x.PAName == passInModel.PAName);


                    var task = Task.Run(() => ProcessRoutineAsync(cycleTickets));

                    await task;

                } while (QueueGlobalVariables.processingCache.Find(
                    x => x.PAName == passInModel.PAName) != null);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Trace("An exception has occured in the queue handler class: " + e.Message);

        }

        return true;
    }
```

And:

```
public async Task<bool> ProcessRoutineAsync(tempTicketData passInModel)
    {

        var ticketInstance = passInModel;

         //Pass item to update routine and await response

** timestamp is fine here
        await UpdateRoutineAsync();
** timestamp changes (after second call is processed)          
        ....

var originalTimestamp = QueueGlobalVariables.processingCache.Find(
            x => x.projectAreaName == passInModel.PAName && x.workitemId == passInModel.recordId).timeStamp;


var instanceTimestamp = ticketInstance.timeStamp;

if (originalTimestamp == instanceTimestamp)
        {
            //Ticket was found in global cache and the timeindex matches

            //Remove item from cache
            var result = QueueGlobalVariables.processingCache.Remove(QueueGlobalVariables.processingCache.Find(
                x =>
                    x.projectAreaName == ticketInstance.PAName && x.recordId == ticketInstance.recordId));



        }
        return true;

    }
```

And:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(tempTicketData))]
public class MyTicketModel
{
    public string recordId { get; set; }
    public string PAName { get; set; }
    public string ItemA { get; set; }
    public string ItbmB { get; set; }
}


[XmlInclude(typeof(tempTicketData))]
public class tempTicketData : MyTicketModel
{
    public DateTime timeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

**** UPDATE

I've found a workaround which fixes the problem, but I'm still confused as why it's happening in the first place :o/

I've amended the QueueProcessor so another variable holds the timestamp exclusively:

```
   var ticketInstance = passInModel;
   var saveTimeIndex = ticketInstance.timeStamp;
```

I then pass the new variable to my if statement that compares the timestamp of the ticket just processed vs. what is in the cache.  Now everything is working OK.  But surely this new variable shouldn't be needed in the first place?

Comment: do you call QueueProcessor() method twice in a row with the same argument ?

Comment: in the ProcessRoutine method it removes an entry from the global cache if the timestamps match.  Which at the moment is always the case. The loop in the QueueProcessor only triggers one call to ProcessRoutine when there should be two.

Comment: Can you show us the tempTicketData class (or struct, or whatever it is...)?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the original question to show how I've constructed the model.

Comment: `tempTicketData` is a class. If somebody modifies it, everyone sees the change (eventually). The ticket is not copied when you do `(tempTicketData)passInModel`, it's still a reference to the same ticket.

Comment: That's the thing though, I am copying it out to another variable in the first line of the ProcessRoutine method:  var ticketInstance = passInModel;  So I wouldn't expect the contents of the variable 'ticketInstance' to pickup any changes.  I've just updated my question with a workaround I've found, might shed some light as to the cause, but i'm still none the wiser :o)

Comment: @Sulphy Are you coming from a C++ background or some such language? C# classes are *not* C++ classes (and C# structs aren't C++ structs). When you "copy" the class to your local, you only copy the reference, not the underlying object. Since everyone sees the same instance of the ticket, they will see your change as well.

Comment: Ahhh gotha, no, I haven't any C++ background, more VB.  This is the first time i've seen this happen and I did wonder if there was some referencing going on rather than a straight copy.  And I guess that explains why my workaround works, because it's not referencing tempTicketData.  Is there some best practice / approach to duplicating a dataset in the fashion I'm trying to do?

Comment: That would be way too broad. For example, it doesn't make much sense to have the timestamp stored by making a derived class. What you really want is to have some container object, that contains both your ticket, and the timestamp. This container object can easily be a `struct`, for example, which would then have the value semantics you expect by default. It's always tricky to cache mutable data, especially in a multi-threaded environment; that's another thing you're probably not used to from VB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tempTicketData` is a class. In C#, all `class`es are reference types. All the references pointing to an instance of a class point to *one* copy of the data. When you change this common copy, everyone sees the change (eventually - multi-threading is hard).

The ticket is not copied when you do `(tempTicketData)passInModel`, it's still a reference to the same ticket. So when you modify it later, you modify the ticket that's in your cache, not just your local - the local is just a reference to the object in the cache, not a copy of the object.

This is a very big deal. Make sure you understand how this works *perfectly* - it's one of the basics of programming, and it's also one of the *major* hurdles in understanding programming.

In general, this is a problem of indirection. Let's imagine a simple virtual machine that represents your (simplified) program.

You have a `tempTicketData` object, a piece of paper, stored in the fridge, in box C42. On the piece of paper, you've written `Hi!`. Your cache object has a post-it note saying "my object is stored in the fridge, in box C42". Now, when you read your ticket from the cache, all you're reading is the post-it note - it's just that due to the way C# works, this also gives you access to all the members of the *real* instance. So when you use code like `Console.WriteLine(ticket.timeStamp)`, C# looks at the post-it, goes to the fridge, and reads you the paper.

Now, when you make your local, `ticketItem`, you copy the post-it - it also says "my object is stored in the fridge, in box C42". When you change `ticketItem.timeStamp`, you're going to the fridge, to box C42, and replacing the paper. Unsurprisingly, when somebody reads the original post-it and goes to the fridge, he'll see your change as well - there's only one `tempTicketData` object. The fact that multiple post-it notes refer to the same location in the fridge doesn't help - there is only one ticket.

Comment: I love the oversimplification :D