# Save/keep the value of a variable while waiting for a long task

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a method `ReceiveMessages()` which receives messages asynchronously. Each message has a parameter called `executionId`. When a message is received, I get the `executionId` and then I perform an awaitable long task called `RunScript()`, which can take up to 20 minutes. After the `RunScript()` task is done, I use the `executionId` of the message to write data to database. However, when a new message arrives before the `RunScript()` is done with the previous message, the `executionId` is changed and I am not able to save data in database with the original `executionId`.

the code is as the following:

```
public class Job
{
    private Guid _executionId;

    Private async Task ReceiveMessages(message)
    {
       DirectExecRequestDto deserializedMessage = new DirectExecRequestDto();
       deserializedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DirectExecRequestDto>(message);

       executionId = deserializedMessage.ExecutionId;

       await RunScript(message); //this task can take a long time while messages are being received

       // here executionId is changed to the recently received message
       // I want to use the executionId related to the original message
       SaveResultsInDatabase(ResultsDirectory, executionId); 
    }
}
```

How can I tackle this issue?

Comment: Couldn't you add these to a queue or something, then use this queue to process your data?

Comment: Declare `executionId` as a local variable inside the method rather than a field variable? Am I missing something about why it needs to be a field variable?

Comment: @zaggler if it's local, then a second call will create another variable, therefore the value won't be overwritten

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# await task - local variables being changed unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651226/c-sharp-await-task-local-variables-being-changed-unexpectedly)

Comment: I have a similar system. In this context what I do is create a new Job instance for each "message". In other words every time a new operation is initiated (whether through API call or otherwise) I create a new Job instance and that object holds all the context needed for the job. Does that make sense?

Comment: Unrelated: Why is `ReceiveMessages`  `private`?

Comment: Is `RunScript` I/O-Bound or CPU-Bound? Or mixed? I have the suspicion DataFlow could be interesting for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store it as an object-level field. Just store it in a locally declared variable instead.

When you call an async function in the context of an async function, using `await`, the local context is preserved, so when the async function call returns, the local variables that were previously in-scope are restored and available.

How is this done at a deeper level? `async` functions are converted, during compilation, into classes. Local variables in the function are converted to fields on that class, and every chunk of code between `await`s is converted into its own separate method on that class. When you call the async function, an instance of this class is instantiated, and the various "sub-functions" that were created are called at the appropriate moment after the task that they awaited completes. Your local variables are retained as fields in this instance, ready to be consumed by any of the "sub-functions" that the compiler created.

Comment: This answer would be better with an explanation of why this would work. I suspect there's already an answer that explains why however...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think I covered it now. :)